# 2 diff commit from same branch but diff merge?

Tags: github, merge-conflict-resolution

I have created a branch and committed to it, got it reviewed and merged with main branch. Now when I try to push another change into another commit with the same branch now I see 2 commits on the branch and if I now merge, the first commit as well as the second will get merged? why is this happening?

Comment: What does "merged" mean? Really merge, or "squash and merge"?

Comment: squash and merge

Comment: Yup, well, there's your answer. You can't reuse a branch if it's being "squash and merge"d. You must delete the branch as soon as it is merged the first time.